# creating a loop around my select Case

Tags: vba, loops, select, case

At present, I have a functioning `Select Case` that states that if a textbox is blank then it is to be highlighted red, but it only seems to be highlighting one of the textboxes. For instance, if 2 textboxes are left blank, it only highlights the first on it comes across.

```
Select Case True
    Case Me.CustName = ""
    Me.CustName.BackColor = &H8080FF
    Case Me.RegAddress = ""
    Me.RegAddress.BackColor = &H8080FF
    Case Me.PostInput = ""
    Me.PostInput.BackColor = &H8080FF
    Case Me.Landline = ""
    Me.Landline.BackColor = &H8080FF
    Case Me.Contact = ""
    Me.Contact.BackColor = &H8080FF
    Case Me.DOBInput = ""
    Me.DOBInput.BackColor = &H8080FF
End Select
```

Being new to VBA, my only thinking is to create a loop round my current code that state (loop until x,y or z is <> "")  but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select Case` runs the code block following the first matching `Case` statement only. If you need to check each of your conditions regardless, you should write them as individual `If` statements instead:

```
If Me.CustName   = "" Then Me.CustName.BackColor   = &H8080FF
If Me.RegAddress = "" Then Me.RegAddress.BackColor = &H8080FF
If Me.PostInput  = "" Then Me.PostInput.BackColor  = &H8080FF
....
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `Select Case` for the wrong purpose.  Its purpose is to test a single expression and execute *one* branch based on the value of that expression.

What you need to do is test each of your text boxes individually, using if statements:

```
If Me.CustName = "" Then Me.CustName.BackColor = &H8080FF

'etc.
```